# I cannot seem to get React to work

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx, babeljs

I have been trying to setup webpack, babel, and npm to work with react. I followed the guide on codeacademy - https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-setup-v. On their last step, they say to create an App.js. Now App.js is a js file, therefore no JSX synthax can be written. This is how my App.js looks:

```
var React = require('react');
var Component = React.createClass({
    render: function (){
        return(
        <p>Hello World</p>
        )
    }
});
module.exports = Component;
```

Now, I know why it throws me an error of unexpected token at line 5 of the code. JS does not recognize the paragraph tag. I tried converting the file to jsx, but that way I cannot import it in my index.js file. I have been trying to setup react for days, and it is very frustrating because I just want to start coding with React very soon.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/README.md#creating-an-app

Comment: Use create-react-app to create a bootstrapped version of the environment. It'll get you up and running quicker than trying to learn everything from scratch. You'll pick up more of the basics looking at an already working environment.

Comment: the link on the first comment is the best way to get everything started